# How do I create this kind of step chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, office365, microsoft-excel-365

I'm trying to make a chart like the image below. Essentially, two companies are splitting a share of profits, but the actual share they're splitting is different depending on a specific threshold. I'm not sure this type of chart is possible to make in Excel without making every piece individually.

All I can think to do is painstakingly create every single quadrilateral in the chart manually and then layer them on top of each other, so of course, hoping for an easier way!

Is there a type of combo chart I can use here? Obviously the areas under the curve need to be customized, but the numbers or scales themselves don't matter since once it's charted I can tweak things. Is this even possible?

[image: Profit function with different profit split over time]

Comment: You can probably do something that comes close with a Combo chart that has a line for Firm A and columns for Firm B

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, let's look at 2 thresholds... one at 25%, and one at 35%. So in both scenarios, Firm B gets a static share of the profit and pretend it's 20%. But Firm A's share grows? So Firm A's share is maybe 25% at a 25% threshold, but maybe 55% at the 35% threshold?

Comment: @Isolated Yes, that's pretty much it. It's a weird chart, I know.

Comment: [Kind of, I guess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jize3.png). There aren't any labels, the angled line is all wavy, and it's an amalgam of 6 series, 4 of which are just drawing lines.

Comment: Like Nomad mentioned, maybe a combo chart will work. Having some sample data may enable some creative responses such as using extra data to create or hide unwanted lines/angles.

Comment: Wow, @EngineerToast, this looks exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of:

[image: Result]

Here's what some bits of the data looks like:

[image: Bit1]

[image: Bit2]

[image: Bit3]

**Setup the data:**

- Overall Table: 100 rows just so it looks kind of smooth. You can make it as tall or short as you want and the lines will be aliased to match.
- Column A: X-axis labels only. Most are blank.
- Column B: How much Firm B gets. I didn't know what numbers you had on the Y-Axis so I just made it 100 total for both firms so the math was easy. Firm B is first so it's on the bottom of the stacked chart.
- Column C: How much Firm A gets. Basically `100-FirmB`.
- Column D: The angled line. I counted from 0-100.
- Column E: One set of horizontal lines. You can't make all the horizontal lines from one series or there will be a slightly angled vertical line as it jumps from one section to the next.
- Column F: The other set of horizontal lines.
- Column G: Single points that will use error bars to create vertical lines.

**Create the chart:**

1. Setup all your data. Get it close and tweak later if you like.
2. Create a combo chart with Column A as the X-Axis, Columns B&C as a stacked chart, and the rest as Lines.
3. Set the Y-Axis max to a fixed value. I used 100.
4. Reduce the gap between the stacked columns to 0%.
5. Add error bars to the Triangle series. Make them plus only with a fixed value of whatever you used for Y-Axis max or larger. We want them to run off the top of the chart. Make them white lines and thick enough that they all merge together.
6. Set the fill of FirmA and FirmB to white with white borders.
7. Change Horiz1 and Horiz2 to black dashed lines.
8. Add error bars to the Vert series, minus only, 100%. Make them black dashed lines.
9. Make the Triangle series a thick black line.
10. Make the Y-Axis a thick black line. (All those white error bars probably overlapped it.)
11. Change the number format for the Y-Axis to ";;;" or set the text color to white to make them disappear.
12. Manually add labels for Firm A and Firm B. (I couldn't find a nice way to do that with chart tools.)

Answer (score 1):

For this type of chart, I'd use an XY/Scatter chart (with lines).  Using a little trigonometry, you can define a basic angle and any vertical segments.  Then plug in a percentage for each horizontal category and it'll easily adjust for different scenarios.  Finally, add two series for the labels and it's completely (and easily) customizable.

[image: concept]

**1) Organize Data**
For this chart, you'll need 5 data series

- Curve
- Thresholds
- Shares
- Firm A Labels
- Firm B Labels

Here's how I set it up.  The values in orange are inputs that can adjust the steepness of the Curve and the Threshold and Share divisions.

[image: organize data]

**2) Create Curve**

[image: create curve]

Then set basic formatting

[image: set format]

**3) Add Thresholds**

[image: add thresholds]

Then format and add error bars for the vertical lines.

[image: thresholds format and error bars]

**4) Add Shares**

[image: add shares]

Then format and add error bars for horizontal lines.

[image: format shares add error bars]

**5) Add Labels**

Add points then add data labels for those points. Adjust the formulas to get the best position and fit.

First, Firm A

[image: firm a labels]

Then, Firm B

[image: firm b labels]

**6) Final Format**

Format to taste.

[image: final format]

**Angles**  A quick note on Excel charting and angles.  If you want angles to appear visually correct, you'll need to do two things:

1. Manually set the charts axis min and max values to prevent Excel's arbitrarily adjusting them.  For a thorough analysis of how Excel calculates axis limits, refer to [Jon Peltier's blog](https://peltiertech.com/how-excel-calculates-automatic-chart-axis-limits/).
2. Adjust the chart dimensions to a square, ensuring that the axis dimension units are the same along both the horizontal and vertical axis.

Comment: Your result is definitely nicer than mine. Can you add a screenshot of the data you used to make it?

Answer (score 1):

We're going to use a stacked area chart for this. Here's how.

The data in the upper left corner of the screenshot below is what we start with. All of the percentage markers except the endpoints have two values, one for the left of the percentage, one for the right.

Important: those are not fractional percentages. You have to enter them as whole numbers and use a custom number format of `0"%"` (zero followed by percent sign in double quotes). This makes the whole numbers display like percentages.

Now insert a row between each pair of duplicate "percent" values as shown by the highlighted rows in the range in the bottom left of the screenshot. Put the "percent" value in the first cell (again, the whole numberwith the custom number format), and zeros in the next two cells. This gives you the vertical lines.

Select this new data range and insert a stacked area chart, the top chart in the image below. Doesn't look right, does it? Let's fix it.

Select the horizontal axis, press Ctrl+1 to format it, and in the task pane, change axis type from automatic to date axis. This produces the chart in the middle. Now it's shaped right, we just need some formatting.

In the Format Axis task pane, change the major units from 1 month to 20 days. Use something like 50% gray for the axis line color. Format each of the area chart series. I used the same 50% gray for the borders of each. I kept the same fill color, but I changed transparency to 50%.

[image: Triangular Stacked Area Chart]